Would God, if He existed, be considered a stroke of luck?
Many, many theistic arguments often point out the sheer luck that would be involved in this universe existing such as through the fine tuning argument or talk about the sheer luck that would be involved in the origin of life or the sheer luck that would be involved in certain reported miracles that have occurred.
But why isn’t God’s existence seen as a form of luck? Surely, it would be quite lucky for the right God to exist to explain a certain phenomenon, no?
As Richard Carrier puts it,

These aren’t just some randomly selected deities from among all logically possible deities (much less all logically possible things), the vast majority of whom will have no interest in creating people or even life (an interest that is hyper-specific within the infinite set of all logically possible interests). And even of those who do, the vast majority of them will be limited, fallible, and morally ambiguous (because there are more logically possible ways to be like that than to be perfect). And by far most randomly selectable gods will be far more empirically obvious—since you also need extraordinarily convoluted reasons for a god not to be. To the contrary, the God the theist needs in order to be a viable explanation for fine-tuning and every other observation is a very specific deity with infinitely convenient knowledge, abilities, and virtues, with an extraordinarily convenient nature even beyond that—they just exist for no reason, yet are still perfectly ordered and capable; and they require no body to remain so perfectly ordered and capable—as well as possessed of a very specific and convoluted set of motivations so bizarre theists will insist they are incomprehensible (see Is a Good God Logically Impossible?).

Are there any philosophers that have thought of God as ultimately a dice roll?

Whose luck? Luck for who?

I wonder what prompted the close vote? Your point is a good one.
